# Running build fails or succeeds depending on previous build

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-3, commit

I'm currently working on a project written in Java with Oracle (H2 for unit tests), Maven, Git, Spring boot, and some other frameworks. Let's say that my project has following commit structure

```
commit A
   |
commit B
   |
commit C
   |
commit D
   |
commit E <- HEAD
```

Commit E builds fine, but when run in IntelliJ, the application fails to start with the error message

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the     classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Via checkouts I run back up my history (E, D, C, B, A) until I find a commit that runs as expected. This seems to be commit A

```
commit A  <- HEAD
   |
commit B
   |
commit C
   |
commit D
   |
commit E
```

Now, when I run down my history again (A, B, C, D, E), all builds run as expected, until I reach commit F again, where it fails to start.

I'm puzzled on why the intermediate commits (B, C, D) succeed or fail to run depending on which was build before them. Can anybody give an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: may be you have an circular dependency. try removing artifact from the repository (.m2 folder) before every build.

Comment: Thank you thinking along. it seemed to be some setting in IntelliJ that I couldn't find. Maven was set to a non-build-in version as was the JDK, but reïnstalling IntelliJ seems to have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be an issue with IntelliJ itself. I uninstalled it, downloaded and installed the new version. Now it runs the last commit without any problems.